# C++ cast to derived pointer or design mistake

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

I have a question about polymorphism

```
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
Base(int v) { u = v; };
    virtual ~Base(){};
    int u;
    void f() { /* operations on u */ };
};

template<class T>
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    T t;
    Derived() { }
    void g() { std::cout << u; /* operations on t and u */ }
};

int main() {
    Base *b = new Base(1);
    b->f();
    if (b->u == 1) {
        Derived<int> *d = dynamic_cast<Derived<int> *>(b);
        d->g();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With d->g() there will be segfault.  Is it possible to access u in a Derived object after cast?  The purpose of the program is to construct a class with an unknown type (information about this can only be available after a class object has been constructed, e.g. a class to read jpg files, the depth information is not known beforehand).  Or is there a design pattern for this kind of problems?  Thanks for any hint.

Comment: But `b` *isn't* a `Derived` object, trying to do what you do is *undefined behavior*. You could look at serialization libraries to see how they handle cases like these, but a common way is to have some meta-data saved that tells the actual type and *size* of the actual object being saved. If you look at e.g. [Microsoft MFC framework](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)  and it's use of [`DECLARE_DYNAMIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywz9k63y.aspx) macro to enable more runtime information.

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer if the conversion fails, which it does in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code segfaults not because there is no `Base::u` in `*b` but because `d` is a `nullptr` and dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. Per the specification, `dynamic_cast<T*>(p)` gives you either

- a pointer to the `T` object that belongs to `*p` if there is one or else
- a `nullptr`.

Since `b` does not point to an object of type `Derived<int>`, you get the `nullptr`. Later on, when you try to use that `nullptr`, your program segfaults.

Note that if you `dynamic_cast` to a reference, the behavior is different.  `dynamic_cast<T&>(r)` will

- give you a reference to the `T` object that belongs to `r` (where `r` is a reference) or
- `throw` an exception of type `std::bad_cast` if there is no such object.

Therefore, you would typically use `dynamic_cast` in either of the following ways.

1. If you want to test the dynamic type of an object and do stuff with it when it is of a certain `class`:

   ```
   if (auto d = dynamic_cast<D*>(b))
     {
       // We have a D object here (d != nullptr), use it.
       d->use();
     }
   else
     {
       // We don't have a D object (d == nullptr) here.
     }
   ```
2. If you (think you) know for sure that the pointer points to an object of (dynamic) type `D`:

   ```
   dynamic_cast<D&>(*b).use();
   ```

In your case, it seems that you have the convention that `b->u == 1` somehow ought to imply that the dynamic type of `*b` is `Derived<int>` so you might consider the `dynamic_cast` to reference. (If nothing else, it would have given you a more helpful error message than “segmentation fault” here.) Of course, now you know how `dynamic_cast` behaves, you might get rid of that “convention” and test the dynamic type directly via a `dynamic_cast` to pointer. Anyway, you will first have to solve the problems described in [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35673258/1392132).

Check out [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for more information on `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: For (2), if you know for sure you have a `D`, you'd use `static_cast<D&>(*b)`. Why have the extra overhead? (maybe `dynamic_cast<D&>()` in the debug build)

Comment: @Barry Unless you have complicated multiple inheritance involved, this would be an option. But it seems reasonable to keep the sanity check in release code, unless the cast is in very hot code. (And thanks for fixing my typo.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

This is because you constructed an instance of `Base`, not an instance of `Derived`. You probably meant to do this:

```
 Base *b = new Derived<int>();
```

But this won't work either, because `Base` does not have a default constructor.

You will never be able to instantiate any `Derived<T>` with this code, because `Derived` tries to use `Base`'s default constructor, but it doesn't have one.

`dynamic_cast<T>` isn't used to create a new instance of a class, attached to an existing one, out of thin air. It's used to resolve an existing instance of a super- or a sub-class, that's related to the class that the instance being dynamically-casted belongs to.